# What is the name of the page element that reads "+ Add telephone" on the Google Hangouts start page?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-hangouts

I'm looking for the name of the page element that reads "**+ Add telephone**" on [Google Hangouts start page](http://hangouts.google.com/start), for the purpose of plugging it into Selenium Python API's `webdriver.Firefox().find_element_by_name()` command.

Alternatively, the element ID would also work, as I know there is also a `find_element_by_id()` command.

Comment: Why cant just go ahead and inspect the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That element does not have any name. Go for xpath contains function and use [find_element_by_xpath](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html)

```
//div[contains(text(),'Add telephone')]
```

However, it's always good idea to not to use Google for any kind of testing. That's kind of trap. Specially for *Selenium*

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the element (using Google Chrome), it looks like this:

```
<div class="c-N-K c-za-b ZG Kn-Mo" role="button" tabindex="0" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">+ Add telephone</div>
```

There's no `name` or `id` on that element. But it is wrapped within a `span` that has a unique `id`!

```
<span id=":sb.og">
    <div class="c-N-K c-za-b ZG Kn-Mo" role="button" tabindex="0" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">+ Add telephone</div>
</span>
```

Alternatively, as @Saifur points out, you can also find by text.